# How to add a new DataGridViewRow with customized font color and font size

Tags: vb.net, winforms, datagridview

How to add new DataGridViewRow with customized Font color and Font size?

I have a DataGridView with 5 columns.

I'm using this code but it causes an `index out of range` exception:

```
Dim NewR As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow

NewR.Cells(0).Value = ""
NewR.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet
NewR.Cells(1).Style.Font = New Font("tahoma", 14)
NewR.Cells(1).Value = "row Materials Customers"
NewR.Cells(2).Value = ""
NewR.Cells(3).Value = ""
NewR.Cells(4).Value = ""

DGVMezan.Rows.Add(NewR)
```

I need to add the new row as I have customized it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here, you're creating a [new DataGridViewRow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.-ctor) without a Template:

```
Dim NewR As DataGridViewRow = New DataGridViewRow()
```

The Row is blank and has no concept of *columns*, so it has no cells.
If you try to access the empty `Cells` collection at any index, you get an `IndexOutOfRangeException`

You can use the [Add()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrowcollection.add) method of the DataGridView's `Rows` collection to generate a new Row, which is then created with an already defined template, so you can access its `Cells` collection.

For example:

```
Dim rowIndex = DGVMezan.Rows.Add()

With DGVMezan.Rows(rowIndex).Cells(1)
    .Style.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet
    .Style.Font = New Font("tahoma", 14)
End With

DGVMezan.Rows(rowIndex).
    SetValues({"Value1", "row Materials Customers", "Value3", "Value4", "Value5"})
```

---

As a note, it's always better having a collection of class objects (or a DataTable), then use this collection as the DataSource of a DataGridView.
Any data added to or removed from the collection of objects, is immediately reflected in the DataGridView, and the UI is updated.

If you try to use the DataGridView as a Spreadsheet, you're going to be disappointed

Answer (score 0):

You should first make sure that the new row you create has the same columns as DGVMezan.

Try using the [DataGridViewRow.Clone Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.clone?view=windowsdesktop-7.0) to create your new row.

```
Dim NewR As DataGridViewRow = DGVMezan.Rows(0).Clone()
NewR.Cells(0).Value = ""
NewR.Cells(1).Style.ForeColor = Color.BlueViolet
...
```